# Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{k=1}^{k=n} (1+ \frac{1}{n}f(\frac{k}{n})) = e^{\int_{0}^{1}f(x) dx}$

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{k=1}^{k=n} (1+ \frac{1}{n}f(\frac{k}{n})) = e^{\int_{0}^{1}f(x) dx}$.

Attempt:  let $\lim \prod_{k=1}^{k=n} (1+ \frac{1}{n}f(\frac{k}{n})) = l$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \log(\prod_{k=1}^{k=n} (1+ \frac{1}{n}f(\frac{k}{n})))= \log l \implies \lim \sum_{k=1}^{k=n} \log(1+ \frac{1}{n}f(\frac{k}{n})) = \log l$.

and working backwards we should have $\log l = \int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{k=n} \frac{1}{n} f(\frac{k}{n})$. So here I'm trying to find the link between $\lim \sum_{k=1}^{k=n} \log(1+ \frac{1}{n}f(\frac{k}{n}))$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{k=n} \frac{1}{n} f(\frac{k}{n})$.

but $\log(1+x) \approx x$ for $x <1$, so in order to use this approximation I have to prove that $\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{k}{n})< 1$ (or maybe I can use the fact that f is continuous and prove that f attains supremum at some point in $[0,1]$) after some terms and I'm stuck .  Is there any other approach which avoids this approximation?

Comment: Hint: $f$ is continuous on a closed interval, hence it must be bounded. Use $\log (1+x)=x+\mathcal{O}(x^2)$.

Comment: Oh yes! I was just thinking about that continuous property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2\right) $$
Since $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2=\int_0^1f(x)^2dx$, then $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2=0$ and thus
$$ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)=\int_0^1 f(x)dx $$

Comment: why is $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2=0$?

Comment: $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2=\int_0^1 f(x)^2dx$, thus when dividing it by $n$ it converges to $0$.